# Make [answers-in-comments] a synonym of [answers-as-comments]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, meta, synonym-request

The tags [answers-in-comments](/questions/tagged/answers-in-comments) and [answers-as-comments](/questions/tagged/answers-as-comments) seem to refer to exactly the same thing: comments that should be answers. Because of that, [answers-in-comments](/questions/tagged/answers-in-comments) should be made a synonym of [answers-as-comments](/questions/tagged/answers-as-comments). It should not be the other way around because [answers-in-comments](/questions/tagged/answers-in-comments) has a lot less questions and no tag wiki.

Comment: I was just thinking the same. Too bad it has been sitting here for almost a year with no progress at all. I doubt there is anyone with score 5 in either of these tags, seeing they are used sparsely. Only 23 and 6 questions respectively.

Answer (score 6):

I have created the synonym as suggested.

I haven't merged the tags as yet.

Answer (score 2):

"Answers as comments" seems ambiguous to me. Does it mean "answers being used as comments" (the content is a comment, but the post is an answer post) or does it mean "answers posted as comments" (the content is an answer, but the post is a comment post)? Both interpretations seem equally plausible.

Ideally, we should keep [answers-in-comments](/questions/tagged/answers-in-comments) and [comments-in-answers](/questions/tagged/comments-in-answers) and get rid of [answers-as-comments](/questions/tagged/answers-as-comments) and [comments-as-answers](/questions/tagged/comments-as-answers).